# Exception handling in Python generator function

Tags: python, exception, generator

I have to create Python function-generator, that should return all divisors of the positive number.
If there are no divisors left function should return None.
Done it this way:

```
def divisor(num):
    try:
        final = (x for x in range(1, num + 1) if num / x == int(num / x))
    except StopIteration:
        return None
    else:
        return final
```

Get such results:

```
three = divisor(3)
next(three) => 1
next(three) => 3
```

But when I call the function **one more time**, get **StopIteration** error:

```
next(three) =>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
StopIteration
```

Why StopIteration is not handled? What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ```yield``` instead of ```return``` ?

Comment: Your question emphasizes "generator function", but you don't have a generator function: you have a normal function that uses `return`. Generator functions must use `yield`. However, the thing you are returning (`final`) is a generator expression. Was that your intent?

Comment: I thought generator expression will let me work with function as a generator function. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the function is not a generator. It is a regular function that returns the generator from the `final` variable on the first call. The best solution, in this case, is to transform the function into an actual generator and omit error handling at all:

```
def divisor(num):
    for x in range(1, num + 1):
        if num / x == int(num / x):
            yield x
    while True:
        yield None
```

Comment: Also, a small side note: instead of `num / x == int(num / x)` you can use `num % x == 0` if `num` is an integer.